# MDX NonEmptyCrossJoin not returning expected results

Tags: ssas, mdx

I am trying to use NonEmptyCrossJoin combined with Extract to return only Members of a given dimension that are relevant. However NonEmptyCrossJoin is not returning the Non Empty tuples.

The following query returns data for the shown EOCs and Index 2.

```
SELECT 
{ [Measures].[MTD BCWP] } ON 0,
{ CROSSJOIN([EOC].[EOC].[EOC], { [INDEX].[INDEX ID].&[2] } ) } ON 1
FROM Metrics
```

```
        |   | MTD BCWP
        | 2 | (null)
G       | 2 | 939482.280
L       | 2 | 7508780.49
M       | 2 | 650
O       | 2 | 151652.62
Unknown | 2 | (null)
```

The same query using NonEmptyCrossJoin returns an empty set.

```
SELECT 
{ [Measures].[MTD BCWP] } ON 0,
{ NONEMPTYCROSSJOIN([EOC].[EOC].[EOC], { [INDEX].[INDEX ID].&[2] } ) } ON 1
FROM Metrics
```

The full query that this is being used in, is much more complicated, but these examples show the crux of the issue. I believe the problem is Dimension or Measure Group configuration related, but don't know what to look for.

The EOC dimension contains only the EOC member.
The Index dimension contains Index Id(PK) and other attributes.
The Measure group includes both Index Id and EOC members that are related to their respective dimensions in addition to other values.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your crossjoin within a nonempty() and provide the relevant measure to non-empty. The Following example will help

```
select 
{
[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
}
on columns,
{
crossjoin([Product].[Subcategory].[Subcategory],{[Geography].[Country].&[United States]})
}
on rows 
from 
[Adventure Works]
```

//this results to

[image: ![enter image description here]

Now we modify our query

```
select 
{
[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
}
on columns,
{
nonempty(
crossjoin([Product].[Subcategory].[Subcategory],{[Geography].[Country].&[United States]})
,
[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount])
}
on rows 
from 
[Adventure Works]
```

//This results to

[image]